# AngularJS variable insertion to another is not copying value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an interesting problem.

```
App.controller('ABCController', function() {
   $scope.valueA = 'abcd';
   var tmp = $scope.valueA;
   /* Do some actions with tmp */
   tmp = tmp.replace('a', 'bc');
   tmp = tmp.split('b');
   ...

   console.log(tmp);
   console.log($scope.valueA);
}
```

The result of console.log is showing updated tmp, but also, $scope.valueA is updated, too, which is same as tmp.

This is not what I expected. In the "var tmp = $scope.valueA" clause, angular provides the pointer of $scope.valueA? Did you face this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `var tmp = angular.copy(value);`

In your case both `tmp` and `value` are pointing to the same location in memory. So any changes in `tmp` will result in a change in `value`. Both `tmp` and `value`  holds the same instance and any update or change will be reflected on both variables.

Comment: Thanks, @Vivz. - So you think, here in "var tmp = value clause", angular provides the pointer of "value" variable to "tmp" variable?

Comment: Yeah. If you update or change any property value, it will update all object referencing the same object. angular.copy creates a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array.

Comment: Thanks @Vivz. I used angular.copy, but getting error: Error: [ng:cpws]. What problem is this?

Comment: You have to copy the object before the loop and use the copied object for updating

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var tmp = value;
 reportList.push({tag : 'abcd',ticker :'bcde',published : true, key:value);
```